# How to open another window and get data from it, then save to a file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program in python using tkinter, and this program is supposed to have a list of books created by the user. On the main window (the one with the list), there should be a menubar with the option to add a book to the list. When clicked, this option should open another window, this time with one entrybox, where the user should enter the book's title and an add button, to add the button to the list.

The list is saved in a .txt file.

This is the program I wrote so far:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def newBook():
    def add():
        BookTitle = v.get()
        bookTitle = '\n' + BookTitle
        books = open('c:/digitalLibrary/books.txt', 'a')
        books.write(bookTitle)
        books.close()

    addWindow = Tk()
    v = StringVar()

    addWindow.geometry('250x40+500+100')

    addWindow.title('digitalLibrary - Add Book')

    newBookEntry = Entry(addWindow,textvariable=v)
    newBookEntry.pack()

    addButton = Button(addWindow, text='ADD', command=add)
    addButton.pack()

def refresh():
    books = open('c:/digitalLibrary/books.txt', 'r')
    bookList = books.readlines()
    books.close()

    for i in range (0, len(bookList)):
        bookOne = Label(text=bookList[i])
        bookOne.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W)

def quitProgram():
    tfQuit = messagebox.askyesno(title='Close Program', message='Are you sure?')
    if tfQuit:
        window.destroy()

window = Tk()
menubar = Menu(window)

window.geometry('400x400+200+100')

window.title('digitalLibrary')

booksmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
booksmenu.add_command(label='Add Book', command=newBook)
booksmenu.add_command(label='Delete Book')
booksmenu.add_command(label='Close Program', command=quitProgram)
menubar.add_cascade(label='digitalLibrary', menu=booksmenu)

books = open('c:/digitalLibrary/books.txt', 'r')
bookList = books.readlines()
books.close()

for i in range (0, len(bookList)):
    bookOne = Label(window, text=bookList[i])
    bookOne.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W)


refreshButton = Button(window, text='Refresh', command=refresh)
refreshButton.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.config(menu=menubar)

window.mainloop()
```

It seems logical to me that this should work, but it just doesn't. When I click the ADD button on the Add Book window, all it does is add the line break to the .txt file.
I know that it works if I use the OS library and create a separate python file for the add book window, but I'd rather put it all in one code, if possible.
I've tried many things, and tried searching it in the web, but I got nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that you are creating more than once instance of `Tk`.  You cannot do this. If you want to create a popup window, create an instance of `Toplevel`. A proper Tkinter application creates exactly once instance of `Tk` with exactly one invocation of `mainloop`.

If your main goal is to simply get input from the user (versus learning how to write your own dialog), you might want to consider using one of the built-in dialogs.

For example:

```
import tkinter.simpledialog as tkSimpleDialog # python 3.x
...
def newBook():
    BookTitle = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Add Book","What is the name of the book?")
    if BookTitle is not None:
        bookTitle = '\n' + BookTitle
        books = open('/tmp/books.txt', 'a')
        books.write(bookTitle)
        books.close()
```